# Java method name error

Tags: java, methods, naming

When i try to compile this code i get this error:

```
dn09.java:38: error: illegal start of expression
                public Tip[] preberi (Scanner sc) {
                ^ dn09.java:38: error: ';' expected
                public Tip[] preberi (Scanner sc) {
                                    ^ dn09.java:38: error: ';' expected
                public Tip[] preberi (Scanner sc) {
                                                ^ 3 errors

[Napaka | process.javac]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is the line of code in the question:

```
public Tip[] preberi(Scanner sc) {
            Tip[] tipi = new tipi[d];
            for (int i = 0; i < tipi.length; i++) {
                String tip = sc.next();
                    switch (tip) {
                        case "prim":
                            tipi[i] = new Prim(sc.nextInt());
                            break;
                        case "arr":
                            tipi[i] = new Arr(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
                            break;
                        case "ostruct":
                            break;
                        case "pstruct":
                            break;
                    }
            }
            return tipi;
        }
```

I have my `Scanner` declared up in the `main()` method, it is imported and everything.

As some of you asked this is my whole code(it isnt in working state at all, as you will also see im a beginner so its preety simple.

```
public class dn09 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    int d = sc.nextInt();
    Tip[] tipi = preberi(sc);
    int u = sc.nextInt();
    int[] ukazi = new int[u];
    for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
        ukazi[i] = sc.nextInt(); //if you know a better way to store 2 numbers where i could then
                                 //use the numbers separately that would be super helpfull as id        
    }                            //need it for 2 switch statements which im currenty trying to 
    for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {//fit into 1.
        switch(ukazi[i]) {
            case 11:
                break;
            case 12:
                break;
            case 13:
                break;
            case 21:
                break;
            case 22:
                break;
            case 23:
                break;
            case 31:
                break;
            case 32:
                break;
            case 33:
                break;
        }
    }


    public Tip[] preberi(Scanner sc) {
        Tip[] tipi = new tipi[d];
        for (int i = 0; i < tipi.length; i++) {
            String tip = sc.next();
                switch (tip) {
                    case "prim":
                        tipi[i] = new Prim(sc.nextInt());
                        break;
                    case "arr":
                        tipi[i] = new Arr(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
                        break;
                    case "ostruct":
                        break;
                    case "pstruct":
                        break;
                }
        }
        return tipi;
    }
}

private static class Prim extends dn09 {
    protected int v;
    public static Prim (int v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
}

private static class Arr extends dn09 {
    protected int n;
    protected int t;
    public static Arr (int n, int t) {
        this.t = t;
        this.n = n;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have this method also declared in your `main` method?

Comment: Paste you whole dn09 class code.

Comment: The problem seems to be before the code you posted. Post a runnable, minimal example. Also, in general you should use a good IDE like Eclipse to help with resolving compile time errors.

Comment: You want to switch over an array (`switch (tipi)`)? That doesn't work.

Comment: I seems you just forgot to put a ';' some where in you code. Put some code before this part. (From a point that you are sure the previous codes are true)

Comment: There us ni name errors. There is a compile error in your switch statement

Comment: I have fixed the switch now i still get the error

Comment: Because the method `public Tip[] preberi(Scanner sc)` is *inside* the `main` method. That cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main() method needs a closing `}` you only close the loop and switch.

You also need to remove the two `static` from your inner classes constructors (`Prim(int)` and `Arr(int,int)`). There is a dangling `}` at the end, perhaps you want to remove the one which closes it?

If you use an IDE and auto-indent the code, those problems get quickly visible.

```
public class dn09 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int d = sc.nextInt();
        Tip[] tipi = preberi(sc);
        int u = sc.nextInt();
        int[] ukazi = new int[u];
        for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
            ukazi[i] = sc.nextInt(); //if you know a better way to store 2 numbers where i could then
            //use the numbers separately that would be super helpfull as id
        }                            //need it for 2 switch statements which im currenty trying to
        for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {//fit into 1.
            switch(ukazi[i]) {
                case 11:
                    break;
...
            }
        }
    }

    public Tip[] preberi(Scanner sc) {
        Tip[] tipi = new tipi[d];
        for (int i = 0; i < tipi.length; i++) {
            String tip = sc.next();
            switch (tip) {
                case "prim":
                    liki[i] = new Prim(sc.nextInt());
                    break;
...
            }
        }
        return tipi;
    }

    private static class Prim extends dn09 {
        protected int v;
        public Prim (int v) {
            this.v = v;
        }
    }

    private static class Arr extends dn09 {
        protected int n;
        protected int t;
        public Arr (int n, int t) {
            this.t = t;
            this.n = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The extra } is there because i was struggling to post the code (just started using the site) even after removing the static from all of the constructors i keep getting the same error

Comment: @LukaTheLegend You need to read all of my answer (especially about closing the main method). I reformatted it for you and added a outline. BTW: You need Java7 to switch on strings.

Comment: I now get a set of errors telling me it cannot find Tip

Comment: You did not provide the  imports, so we cannot possible know what classes you are using. You should not use a class which you do not have...

Comment: Im not using any other classes, when i put the method outside of the main method, its now treating the method as a class

Comment: I suspect you want to return dn09 as the return type of `preberi()´. Then you can make it "return new Arr(...);" or "return new Prim(...);" depending on the input. (but other code will then have to be changed as well). If you do not want to use the common supertype of those two, you should remove the "extends".